# Why do I receive an incorrect syntax error when try to parameterize a table name?

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following code:

```
string strTruncateTable = "TRUNCATE TABLE @TableNameTruncate";
SqlCommand truncateTable = new SqlCommand(strTruncateTable, myConnection);              
truncateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("TableNameTruncate", tbTableName.Text);
truncateTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Whenever I run the application, I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@TableNameTruncate'

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: I updated your title to point real problem. Feel free to edit or rollback it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I fix the issue?

By specifying the table name as part of the SQL. Table and column names can't be parameterized in most database SQL dialects, including SQL Server.

You should either perform very stringent validation on the table name before putting it into the SQL, or have a whitelisted set of valid table names, in order to avoid SQL injection attacks in the normal way.

Comment: So truncating the table also deals with the column name? Is that why?

Comment: @SiKni8: I'm not sure what you mean by "deals with"... I'm just saying that you can only parameterize *values* in SQL, not tables and column names.

Answer (score 1):

You can only parameterized your **values**, not your column names or table names no matter you use DML statements or DDL statements.

And by the way, parameters are supported for *[Data manipulation language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language)* operations not [*Data Manipulation language*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) operations.

Data manipulation language =

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...
UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE ...
DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...
```

[`TRUNCATE TABLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx) is a [Data Definition Language statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx). That's why you can't use `TRUNCATE TABLE` with parameters **even only if you try to parameter a value**. You need to specify it as a part of SQL query.

You might need to take a look at the term called [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: But even within DML, you can't usually specify parameters for the table and column names. And in a database which *did* allow that, I suspect it would allow it for TRUNCATE operations too...

Comment: @JonSkeet Of course. `Parameters` are there for values, not column names or table names. But not using parameters (specify it as a string in `SqlCommand`) will allow the TRUNCATE operations. Also this _Dynamic SQL_ subject is really strange. I don't feel right to use it anywhere :)

Comment: @SonerGönül: My point is that it's not the DML vs DDL part which is the problem here. The OP could change their `TRUNCATE` to `DELETE FROM @TableName` at which point it's DML but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, I see. I updated my answer to point the _real problem_ instead of DML vs DDL comparison. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Jon Skeet, table name cannot be parametrized for truncate operation.

To fix this issue, fully qualified query needed to be written.

So you can put a conditional check by the parameter value @TableNameTruncate and using if or switch case statement create fully qualified query then execute it.

or simply

```
string strTruncateTable = "TRUNCATE TABLE " + TableNameTruncate.Value;
SqlCommand truncateTable = new SqlCommand(strTruncateTable, myConnection);              
truncateTable.Parameters.AddWithValue("TableNameTruncate", tbTableName.Text);
truncateTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What is `TableNameTruncate.Value`? Where does it referenced from?

Comment: TableNameTruncate refers to the sql parameter object for @TableNameTruncate parameter.